# Can I move the location of my git repo from the subdirectory of my project to the main directory of this project without losing the history on GitHub?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I have some project in `Project` directory. And the location of the git repository is `Project/src` subdirectory. I'd like to change the location of my repo to the main directory `Project` without losing GitHub history etc. How can I do it?
After this change, should I commit all files which were not commited before because they were not in the repo? Now every pushed change on a new/old repo will be visible on my remote repo on GitHub? I am using Ubuntu if it's important.

Comment: Just move the .git folder to the new location. I think that will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a repository `movetest` and an empty folder `anothermovetest`. The commands below show that moving the `.git` folder is equal to moving the repository.

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/movetest
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/dev/git/movetest/.git/
```

I then moved the `.git` folder from `movetest` to `anothermovetest`. `ls` shows that `movetest` is no longer a git repository, but `anothermovetest` now is. We've moved the entire git-database which contains all the objects, references, etc (and thus your entire history).

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/movetest (master)
$ ls         

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/movetest
$ cd ../anothermovetest                 

zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/anothermovetest (master)
```